# Insert a check box in html using QT

Tags: html, qt, checkbox

I want to insert a check box in a html using QT. Currently, I can generate a html using QTextEdit, QTextCursor. But I have no idea how to insert a check box.

If somebody has implement this problem, please tell me some details.

ZhQ

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I have found the solution. The code using to generate the html file is:

```
QTextEdit * editor = new QTextEdit();
editor->setAcceptRichText(true);

QTextCursor cursor(editor->textCursor());
cursor.insertText("hello, qt html!!");
cursor.insertBlock();


QTextDocument * pDoc = editor->document();
QString strResult = pDoc->toHtml();

QFile file("test.html");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{        
    return 0;
}
QTextStream out(&file);
out.setCodec("utf-8");
out << strResult;
file.close();
```

In order to insert the check box, the following code is workable:

```
out << "<input type='checkbox'>";
```

And the following code will insert a radio into to a html:

```
out << "<input type='radio', name='type1'>";
out << "<input type='radio', name='type1'>";
```

In the all, the whole code is:

```
QTextEdit * editor = new QTextEdit();
editor->setAcceptRichText(true);

QTextCursor cursor(editor->textCursor());
cursor.insertText("hello, qt html!!");
cursor.insertBlock();


QTextDocument * pDoc = editor->document();
QString strResult = pDoc->toHtml();

QFile file("test.html");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{        
    return 0;
}
QTextStream out(&file);
out.setCodec("utf-8");
out << strResult;
out << "<input type='checkbox'>";
out << "<input type='radio', name='type1'>";
out << "<input type='radio', name='type1'>";
file.close();
```

zhq